# using same where clause on multiple tables before joining them

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a better way of joining two tables and using same where clause on both of them? I am doing it as follows:

```
SELECT a.account_id,
       a.account,
       b.tax,
       b.rate
FROM   (SELECT account_id,
               account
        FROM   accounts
        WHERE  account_id IN (SELECT account_id
                              FROM   account_location
                              WHERE  location = "A")) AS a
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT tax,
                         rate
                  FROM   tax
                  WHERE  tax_id IN (SELECT tax_id
                                    FROM   account_tax
                                    WHERE  account_id IN (SELECT account_id
                                                          FROM   account_location
                                                          WHERE  location = "A"))) AS b
              ON a.account_id = b.account_id
```

I have 4 tables. Accounts, account_location which has list of accounts mapped to locations, tax which has all taxes, account_tax which has mapping of all taxes applicable to each account. The code works fine, but can this be made faster?

Comment: mysql database. Sorry didnt mention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaking, this query should do the same:

```
select
  a.account_id, a.account, t.tax, t.rate
from 
  accounts a
  inner join account_location al 
    on al.account_id = a.account_id 
    and al.location = 'A'
  left join account_tax at
    on at.account_id = a.account_id
  left join tax t on t.tax_id = at.tax_id
```

I think it will be faster do to more efficient joins (MySQL isn't good with subselects, especially in those join conditions. Also, I think it's more readable.

Comment: Ohh...I thought its better to use as less joins as possible?

Comment: Partially true, although it's more subtle. Inner joins are very fast, left joins slightly less although still pretty good. But they get slower when the join conditions get more complex. A join condition with a subselect or even an expression with `or` is a real performance killer, but simple joins like the ones in my answer should work fine, especially if you have proper indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can used derived tables (and possibly alternatively CTE's) to DRY up what you are doing in the subquery. Then join to the derived table, instead of using `IN`. You can do this for the other subqueries as well:

```
Select a.account_id, a.account, b.tax, b.rate 
from
(select account_id from account_location where location="A") as UsefulAccounts
inner join
(
  select account_id, account from accounts acc 
  INNER JOIN UsefulAccounts ua on acc.account_id = ua.account_id
) as a
left join
(
  select tax, rate 
  from tax t
  inner join account_tax actx 
  on t.account_id = acc.account_id
  inner join UseFulAccounts ua on actx.account_id = actx.account_id
) as b 
on a.account_id = b.account_id;
```

Comment: Actually, I like GolezTrol's answer better - it has simplified even further.